# Customize class attribute on div tag using ExtJS

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

What is the best way to customize the class attribute on a div tag. For example, when using Ext.Component, the div tag that gets generated by default is

```
<div class="x-component  x-component-default">...</div>
```

But I just want to create a component with a custom class, like

```
<div class="some-class">...</div>
```

What would be the best way to approach doing that?

If I do use something like

```
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    ...
    baseCls: 'some-class'
});
```

I still get

```
<div class="some-class some-class-default">...</div>
```

I don't really have to use the Ext.Component object if something better is recommended. Im just starting with what I know.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"some-class-default"* is coming from the [ui](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-ui) cls which resolves to 'default' by default.

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nke) where I've overriden Component to not add the default ui.

```
Ext.define('Overrides.Component', {
    override: 'Ext.Component',

    baseCls: 'myComponent',
    borderBoxCls: '',
    setUI: function(ui) {
        var me = this;
        if (me.rendered) {
            me.updateLayout();
        }
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Component', {        
            itemId:'myComponent',        
            html:'My Component',
            renderTo:Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: So you've just defined a new class and instead of extending it, you used the override attribute. That was very helpful. Thank you.